# How A Cord Lock in A Window Unlocks

Tags: mechanisms, pulleys, product-engineering

In this video(https://youtu.be/QvLdVWS_DsM) it says that a cord lock works like this: there is a cylinder which the string moves around, and there is another cylinder which is rough. When you pull out and let go, the string catches on the rough cylinder. The cylinder and string both go up, and the rough cylinder stops when the groove ends, and pinches the string so it stops.

[image: a picture showing the above]

But then how it unlocks is unclear to me. It says you have to pull to the center of the window horizontal side, so the rope lets go. But I don't understand why you need to pull to the center.

Could someone please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You don't need to pull to centre to **release** the lock and allow it to fall to the bottom of its slot.

You **do** need to pull to centre to lower the blind to prevent the string picking up the lock and re-engaging it.

---

Note that when the string is vertical as shown above it presses lightly on the locking cylinder driving it to the left. The falling blind will cause the string to pull up through the lock and the cylinder will rotate anti-clockwise. Since it is being pressed against the left side of the slot it will climb and eventually be cammed over against the roller and clamp the string. Pulling the string will unlock the clamp whether pulled vertically or to the right as explained above.

It's rather clever!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture of one in my blinds.

The serrated roller is the movable one.

The cord is nearly vertical and it touches the serrated roller.

The cord will lock if released in this orientation, and has to be held towards the right to prevent locking.

[image]